How to fetch Metadata in glue job
I want to fetch Metadata of a s3 bucket (with prefix) from a glue job. Like I want to get filename, time of creation, file size etc.
Inside my glue job (pyspark) I'm converting csv files to parquet and storing them in some s3 location, and I want to get this parquet files details.
I tried using paginator from boto3 but it wasn't working. Is there any simpler approach?

A small suggestion to increase the likelihood of your question being answered:  mention in the question title that it's the S3 metadata that you are interested in.  Most people just skim through looking at the titles of open questions.

You can use something like this :
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

def print_s3_files_name_and_size(bucket_name, source_folder):
    for bucket_file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=source_folder):
        file_name = bucket_file.key
        file_last_modified_date = bucket_file.size
        print(f"File: {file_name}, file_last_modified_date : {file_last_modified_date } ")

